# Windows Bootmanager on two NVMe drives

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bcd

I have two nvme slots on my board, in one of which I have run Win 10 Pro for the past couple of years. Now I upgraded to a bigger nvme Drive and put that in the same slot, moving the old one to the other slot. So far so good, they are connected in PCIe Mode NOT in SATA Mode.

Since my system on the old drive is fairly neatly configured, I wanted to keep it around for the time being and use a dual boot scenario. So, this is the problem:

I installed Win 10 Pro on the freshly formatted New drive. A dual boot menu was created by the installer (or rather an entry added) using the original EFI-Boot Partition located on the Old Drive.
It didn't work, no matter what I did try to repair/fix it, (I tried about everything that's possible from `bootrec /fixboot /rebuildbcd bcdedit bcdboot ..` I read and followed about a dozen guides, I was not able to solve my problem. I could not boot into Win 10 on the new Drive. I always received this error: `Error Code 0xc00000e  -  an important hardware device wasn't detected by Windows 10` -

But here it gets interesting: EXCEPT when booting from the USB drive I used to install Win 10 with, and launching the cmd from within it (Shift F10).

***I noticed something courious: When booting from the EFI-Bootloader on the nvme drive, it says:***

**Windows 10 on Volume 8** (the new nvme, error 0x0000e)

**Windows 10 on Volume 12** (the old nvme, works)

***by arriving at the OS-Selector screen this way: `Boot from USB-Drive->Shift+F10->exit cmd->launch different OS`, I can boot into both OSes but the volumes have changed:***

**Windows 10 on Volume 9** (the new nvme, works)

**Windows 10 on Volume 16** (the old nvme, works)

---

I tried to edit the Bootloader using bcdedit but I don't know how to see what volume is what drive since it changes depending on where you are at what stage. Launching the Commandprompt from advanced start-up options lists different drives and volumes than does the repair computer route when booting from USB... It's too confusing now I've been woking on it for hours maybe someone has a hint on what is going on.

If the hardware matters at all: the board is a `ASUS Prime Z390-A` and the drives are `Samsung 890 (new) and 970 Evo (old)`

Edit: Bootconfig and diskpart list volume taken from the Old System

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     I   Iota         NTFS   Partition    447 GB  Healthy    ssd
  Volume 1     L   Lightroom    NTFS   Partition    223 GB  Healthy    ssd
  Volume 2     J                       Removable       0 B  No Media    
  Volume 3     D   Drive        NTFS   Partition     59 GB  Healthy    usb-drive
  Volume 4     S   8Ball        NTFS   Partition   7452 GB  Healthy    HDD
  Volume 5     Z   wagon        NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy    ssd
  Volume 6     T   1TB SSData   NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy    ssd
  Volume 7     V   Versatile    NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy    ssd
  Volume 8     H                NTFS   Partition    784 GB  Healthy    nvme 980 NEW
  Volume 9                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 10                     NTFS   Partition    508 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 11    C                NTFS   Partition    232 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 12                     NTFS   Partition    499 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 13    F   ESD-USB      FAT32  Removable   7617 MB  Healthy
  Volume 14    O   UBUNTU 19_1  FAT32  Removable     59 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...

C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume7
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {38ed9ec0-1530-11ec-aaf5-8c8da841d03a}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 5

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=H:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=H:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {38ed9ec0-1530-11ec-aaf5-8c8da841d03a}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {38ed9ebe-1530-11ec-aaf5-8c8da841d03a}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

---

Comment: [At a minimum we need to know what your boot configuration data looks like](https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.9b9d9c88f30cfe016bf27906918a542f?rik=4RKK%2b4%2fi7u78cQ&pid=ImgRaw&r=0). Please edit your question to include that vital information

Comment: 0x0000e = corrupt or misconfigured boot data. Seeing that after moving the drive doesn't surprise me. I'm betting the USB surrenders the control of the boot process to the laptop _after_ the drives have been detected. Its boot data is _not_ misconfigured so no errors; and it detects the drives independently so it IDs them independently. Put the old drive back where it was; I'd expect a successful boot into the old OS. Put the new drive to the empty slot, and you'll see the error there. That's where I'd start fixing - or if it's a new install I'd just forget about it and reinstall.

Comment: No. I moved the old SSD with the old Win 10 install on it and it booted just fine. I installed Win 10 on the new one and could not boot into the new one. I deleted the EFI-Partition on the old Drive, formatted the new nvme drive to start from scratch. Installed Win 10 on it and thus forcing it to create a new EFI-Partition on the new drive -> same error 0x0000e only this time I get it when trying to boot into the old System. Circumvent the issue by booting from USB. It seems this way other boot config is used